# Secure this invaluable documentation on using C/C++ with GSSAPI and SASL

Tags: c++, c, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

I have been working on using GSSAPI in c/c++ applications, for some time now.
Obviously I had to google and research a lot.
One of the most interesting documentation I discovered was on Sun's old web-site.
After Oracle took over Sun, the old web-site is gone, and but somehow this information exists.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4863/index.html
Alarmingly, I couldn't find any link to the above url in Oracle's documentation.
The content also included a couple of PDF files, which I luckily have preserved on my laptop.

The above URL also has an excellent guide on using SASL with c/c++.

The content referred to some tar file that contained sample source code. 
As per the current site content this file should be available at:
http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=41912db5
But unfortunately I can't locate them on the site now.

The content is an excellent starting point for a c/c++ programmer starting fresh on GSSAPI / Kerberos / PAM / SASL

Looking at Oracle's present site I strongly believe the content is presently left behind "accidentally" and will be soon gone.

Now here's my question to the fantastic hacks that visit stackoverflow:

1. Can you somehow replicate the content to some place, so that everybody can enjoy it's benefits?
2. Does anybody have a copy of the tar-ball that I am referring to? and would you be willing to share it?
3. Where must I upload these PDFs so that everybody can easily benefit?

I think the content is truly invaluable, and I can't think of any other web-source for such painstakingly clear information on using GSSAPI with C/C++.
If you can do something about this, please do it now, because I think the above URL will be soon gone too.

My sincere thanks in advance, and I promise you many others will thank you too.

Edit:
A bit of hunting around on Oracle's site and I discovered the link to one of the PDF's, but has been given a new name:
[Oracle Solaris Security for Developers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4863/816-4863.pdf)
Surely a gem of a reference if you are beginning to use GSSAPI / SASL with c++

Comment: Have you tried Google's cache feature, or the WayBack machine?

Comment: @user946850 ok I tried the wayback machine, it did take me to the original listing page, but i forgot it required some proprietary sun download manager. Guess we must bounce this post to some kind hearted old sun technician.

Comment: If you want to grab a copy of the website before the kind hearted Sun technician noticies the errors of their ways and purges their Server of these files, try letting http://www.httrack.com/ loose on their page to save as much as possible.

Comment: No such thing as "C/C++". Pick a language.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the ["Internet Archive"](http://archive.org/index.php) is what you are looking for. You can also check out the  ["Archive-It"](http://www.archive-it.org/) and other similar resources listed at [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive).

Answer (score 2):

This text is copyrighted. Whatever you do, the right thing to do is getting permission from Oracle/Sun first. Maybe this guide is outdated or simply wrong in places, and they decided to take it offline.

- If you want it replicated -- do it!
- There is a Firefox Addon called [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/scrapbook/). It does a fine job archiving whole sites, when done you can copy the data from your profile to anywhere you want. Say a Web Server serving the static content.
- There is also a wiki site by Oracle [wikis.oracle.com](http://wikis.oracle.com/), which already contains similar content. Namely some PDFs with similar guides. I assume it's quite safe putting "your" PDF there.